# Resource leak input is never closed - where/when do i close and how?

Tags: java

I tried closing it but i'm not sure where to put the input.close();, im really new to all this and asking my professors risks me losing points. Also i'm not sure if i should keep the second to last system.out monthly payment is, or get rid of it. Does it even make sense with the rest of my code?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Project2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Yearly interest rate
        System.out.print("Enter annual interest rate, for example 0.5, no percent sign:");
        double annualInterestRate = input.nextDouble();

        //Monthly interest rate
        double monthlyInterestRate = annualInterestRate / 1200;

        //Number of years
        System.out.print("Enter number of years, for example 5: ");
        int numberOfYears = input.nextInt() ;

        //Loan amount
        System.out.print("Enter investment amount, for example 145000.95: ");
        double loanAmount = input.nextDouble();

        //Calculate payments
        double monthlyPayment = loanAmount * monthlyInterestRate / (1
                - 1 / Math.pow(1 + monthlyInterestRate, numberOfYears * 12));
        double totalPayment = monthlyPayment * numberOfYears * 12;

        System.out.println("The monthly payment is " + 
        (int) (monthlyPayment * 100) / 100.0);

        System.out.println("Accumulated value is " +
        (int) (totalPayment * 100) / 100.0);
```

Comment: If asking your professor is risky, you might not have been listening in your class... but you should ask as it shows you are willing to learn. Also, read [ask] cause I can't see a real question here.

Comment: My professor is.. well he isnt the nicest man. My question is how do i close my input. I am getting an error on eclipse saying "resource leak: input is never closed" How do i close it and where do i put the code?

Comment: Simply call the close method when you don't need *input* anymore. Preferably in a finally block (google around to find why). If you're using Java 7+, use a try-with-resources statement.

Answer (score 5):

Traditionally, you should put the `close()` call in a `finally` block so it's called regardless of any exception you'd have on the way:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
try {
    // Use input
} finally {
    input.close();     
}
```

However, since Scanner is AutoClosable, Java 7 offers a cleaner syntax to do this:

```
try (Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    // Use input
}
```

Comment: The second autoclosable method you mentioned doesnt seem to be working for me. I tried both methods and it says input cannot be resolved and that input is still not closed

Comment: Are you using Java 7?

Comment: I'm at the dentist right now but I downloaded the newest java and eclipse about 2 weeks ago so if 7 is the newest than I would imagine so. When I do the finally portion is doesn't seem to close the Input, do I have to put that below the last like I used Input? I put it right after the input scanner line to try it and all the other inputs became errors as expected

Comment: Maybe it is just my placement of the finally method?

Answer (score 4):

Simply use a [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement:

```
try (Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    // code using input
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add input.close when you are done using the Scanner class